# Using array initializer

Tags: c#

I have a class called `Matrix : IEnumerable<double>`, (classic, mathematical matrix. It is basically a 2D array with some goodies).

The class is immutable, so there is no way to change its values after instance creation.

If want to create a matrix with pre-existing values I have to pass an array to the constructor like this:

```
double[,] arr = new double[,]
{
    {1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9}
};
Matrix m = new Matrix(arr);
```

Is there a way to turn it into this: (?)

```
Matrix m = new Matrix
{
    {1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9}
};
```

**Update:**

Found a hack-ish way yo make it work. I'm not sure if this solution is advisable, but it works.

```
class Matrix : ICloneable, IEnumerable<double>
{
        // Height & Width are initialized in a constructor beforehand.
        /*
         * Usage:
         * var mat = new Matrix(3, 4)
         * {
         *              {1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9}, {10,11,12}
         * };
         */
        int rowIndex;
        bool allowArrayInitializer;
        double[,] tempData;
        double[,] data;
        public void Add(params double[] args)
        {
                if(!allowArrayInitializer)
                        throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot use array initializer");
                if(args.Length != Width || rowIndex >= Height)
                        throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid array initializer.");
                for(int i = 0; i < Width; i++)
                        tempData[i, rowIndex] = args[i];
                if(++rowIndex == Height)
                        data = tempData;
        }
}
```

Comment: Of course you can do `Matrix m = new Matrix(new double[,]{{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9}});`

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Not what I was aiming for :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not if it’s immutable; that syntactic sugar is implemented using `Add()`.

Comment: With an interface? Would be nice to know, sometimes this is useful.

Comment: Does the `Add()` method have to be public? I could live with it being mutable-if-you-don't-want-to-use-reflection.

Comment: @FelixK.: I’m not sure, but I don’t think so. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb384062.aspx is all I’ve found so far…

Comment: @FelixK.: [It has to implement `IEnumerable[<T>]` but not `IList` or anything.](http://ideone.com/BMdbHW)

Comment: @GiladNaaman Maybe [this](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/09/18/non-iterable-collection-initializers.aspx) will help :)

Comment: It looks interesting. Is this how the vanilla arrays are implemented? If yes, how does the 2D arrays implement this?

Comment: @GiladNaaman: No, it’s not how vanilla arrays are implemented; arrays are a… more special feature of the language. They’ve also been around for much longer.

Comment: Fine. Thanks. So i can use this for my own collections, didn't know this ( and never tried to ).

Comment: I thought of a way to implement this, but it is memory intensive and it requires a call to a constructor.

Comment: @GiladNaaman: That’s horrible and beautiful at the same time =D

Answer (score 0):

You will not able to do it via initializer but should be able to do it via parameterized constructor.
You can see the sample code below :

```
class Matrix : IEnumerable<double>
{
    double[,] input;
    public Matrix(double[,] inputArray)
    {
        input = inputArray;
    }

    public IEnumerator<double> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return (IEnumerator<double>)input.GetEnumerator();
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return input.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

In the main method :

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var m = new Matrix(new double[,] { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 }, { 7, 8, 9 } });
    }
```

I hope this helps you!

Comment: I don't see how it differs from the example I gave in the original post.

Comment: This is… what the question wanted to avoid?

Comment: @Gilad Naaman, I took around 15 mins to type, test and post. After posting I realized you have given the BEST answer !!!. Please do not simply reduce the points!

Answer (score 0):

instead of deriving from `IEnumerable`  I would use a property:

```
class Matrix 
{
        public double[,] Arr { get; set; }
}

Matrix m = new Matrix
{
      Arr = new double [,] { {1d,2d,3d}, { 4d,5d, 6d}}
};
```